# No emulator images (avds) found OS X ionic

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, ionic-framework

Attempting to emulate an Ionic/Cordova application on android on OS X.

I've:

- installed Android SDK
- added android sdk and build tools to bash_profile
- installed Android Packages (see below)
- Setup a few AVDs using the ui (see below)

I am able to run `ionic build android` successfully. However whenever I run `ionic emulate android`. I receive  `No emulator images (avds) found` - what am I missing?

[image: SDK Tools Installed]

[image: AVD Image list]

Answer (score 0):

Try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/),its a fast third-party emulator that can be used instead of the default Android emulator. In some cases it's as good as or better than developing on actual devices! after installing and launching the avd build the package via the command

```
ionic build android
```

and run the application in the avd via the following command

```
ionic run android
```

this can possibly solve your issue.